# STL function for hourly / minute data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a time series that I want to decompose using STL. The data has 1 row per min. I have the data for 10 days (the dataset is the one that comes pre-loaded with twitter's anomaly detection API)  and I want to find seasonality within a day (e.g. activity peaks from 9pm to 11pm)

While decomposing with `STL` however, I get an error

> "series is not periodic or has less than 2 periods".

I understand this is because the time frame of data should be >2yrs. However since I want to check seasonality within a day , is there a way to tell `STL` to look for seasonality within a day ?

I tried using frequency option in `xts` while converting to time series format but doesn't work (1440 = no. of minutes in a day)

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection")
library(AnomalyDetection)
library(xts)

#data is part of the pacakage anomaly detection 
data(raw_data)
View(raw_data)

#converting raw_data to xts format 

raw_data_ts <- ts(raw_data$count, as.POSIXct(raw_data$timestamp, format='%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S'), frequency = 1440)
raw_data_ts1<-as.ts(raw_data_ts)

# Using STL for seasonal decomposition 
modelStl <- stl(raw_data_ts1, s.window = "periodic")
```

Comment: In the documentation of `stl `it is said that `x` has to be an object of class `ts`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: xts is another type of time series format . I am not sure if this is the problem( the error message seems to suggest it can understand the data but cannot find 2 periods) . Will try with ts once though.

Comment: Be sure to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This makes it much easier to answer a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your error:

```
date_seq<-seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 24)
data<-sin(1:24)+rnorm(24)

> stl(xts(x=data, date_seq, 2*pi),s.window="periodic")
```

This gives your error. It is in german but does mean the same.

> Error in stl(xts(x = data, date_seq, 2 * pi), s.window = "periodic") : 
>   Zeitreihe ist nicht periodisch oder umfasst weniger als zwei Perioden

If I use `ts` instead of `xts` it works fine:

```
stl(ts(data=data, start = 1, frequency = 2 * pi), s.window="periodic")
```

*edit in response to updated question

This works for me:

```
install.packages("devtools") 
devtools::install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection") 
library(AnomalyDetection)

time_series<-ts(data=raw_data[,2], start = 1, frequency = 1440)
plot(stl(time_series, s.window = "periodic"))
```

[image]

Comment: Nope still have erros .tying to get the code to you (sorry new to this . Still figuring out the markdown format )

Comment: I updated the answer. If you have any questions to this feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me too